# Верстка HTML, чтобы содержимое помещалось в экран

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как в этом макете сделать так, чтобы блоки `nav` и `footer` были соответственно сверху и внизу, всю остальную видимую часть занимал блок page_wrapper.

Т.е. в итоге нужно чтобы все содержимое страницы помещалось на страницу (без прокрутки), а содержимое page_wrapper можно было прокручивать

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <title>Страница</title>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
   Menu
</nav>

<div class="page_wrapper">
    Content
</div>

<footer>
    Footer
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0;
}

nav,
footer{  
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
}

.page_wrapper {  
  max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">Menu</nav>
<div class="page_wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit autem qui nostrum obcaecati repudiandae cupiditate quod aut totam error eos, sunt a, corporis dolor aliquam ut rem inventore expedita quidem.</p>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Спасибо, этот ответ то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 1000%;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  border: solid;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  border: solid;
  bottom: 0;
  position: sticky;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Страница</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    Menu
  </nav>

  <div class="page_wrapper">
    Content
  </div>

  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```